# Query to pick value depending on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, select

I have a table with exchange rates which update only when a new exchange rate comes, that is, the only the date that the new rate entered is recorded. however the system has logic to say if any date fall within a particular date, it picks the corresponding exchange rate

[image]

i would like to have a query which picks the required exchange rate given any date supplied, i.e., pick the rate from the period.

```
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(    SELECT cast('2015-11-01' as date) AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < getdate())
SELECT  ld.AllDates,cr.effective_from,cr.rate_against_base
FROM ListDates ld
left join CurrencyRatetable cr on cr.effective_from between cr.effective_from and ld.alldates
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Comment: Use `BETWEEN x and y` and make sure that the date x is stripped all the time data, and date y has time not a second fraction beyond range because values here are inclusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` together with a `TOP 1` subselect.

Something like:

```
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS (
    SELECT cast('2015-11-01' as date) AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < getdate()
)
SELECT ld.AllDates, cr.effective_from, cr.rate_against_base
FROM ListDates ld
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM CurrencyRatetable cr
    WHERE cr.effective_from <= ld.alldates
    ORDER BY cr.effective_from DESC
) cr
ORDER BY ld.AllDates
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Both `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` are like a join to a subselect. The difference is that `CROSS APPLY` is like an inner join and `OUTER APPLY` is like a left join.

Make sure that CurrencyRatetable has an index on effective_from for efficient access.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e6u7dsCz).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to achieve the required result using the window function `LEAD`. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(effective_from date, rate_against_base decimal(19,4))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2000-01-01', 1.6)
,('2016-10-26', 1)
,('2020-07-13', 65.8765);

DECLARE @searchDate DATE = '2023-01-17';

WITH cte AS(
SELECT effective_from
      ,ISNULL(LEAD(effective_from) OVER (ORDER BY effective_from), CAST('2049-12-31' AS DATE)) AS effective_to
      ,rate_against_base
  FROM @t
)
SELECT rate_against_base
  FROM cte
  WHERE @searchDate >= effective_from
    AND @searchDate < effective_to
```